# This method is an undefined type of object

Tags: java, android, eclipse, methods

I am trying to access the setName method from the WebView class but i get an error when i get an error in the call callSetNameFunction. I create and new webview object and stored it in the object in the webfragment class but doesnt have access to the methods in the webview class. How can i do that. I havent done java for long, still learning.

WebView class

```
public class WebView {

    private String name;

    public WebView (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public WebView () {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if(name != null) {
            this.setName(name);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thats not his name");
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }   
}
```

WebFragment class

```
public class WebFragment {

    Object myObject;

    public WebFragment() {
        myObject = new WebView();
    }

    public Object getWebView() {
        return myObject; 
    }

    public void callSetNameFunction() {
        myObject.setName();
    }
}
```

Comment: missing argument for `setName` in your `callSetNameFunction()`

Comment: If you solve this and run it, you're going to get a `StackOverflowError` because the `setName` method is going to call itself in an infinite recursive call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 corrections

- `Object myObject` must be `WebView myObject;`
  <sub>*If you want to use methods from `WebView` object, you must declare `myObject` attribute of `WebFragment` class as a `WebView` type if you want to use the methods it declares.*

  **NOTE:** You must change also `getter` signature to `public WebView getWebView() {`</sub>
- `myObject.setName();` should receive a parameter i.e: `myObject.setName("name");`
- Constructor without parameters does not make effect when asign a variable:

  ```
  public WebView () {
      this.name = name;  // Warning: The assignment to variable name has no effect
  }
  ```

  must be:

  ```
  public WebView () {
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

change your methods to following

```
public void setName(String name) {
    if(name != null) {
        //this.setName(name);
       this.name=name;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Thats not his name");
    }
}
```

and also this :

```
public void callSetNameFunction() {
    WebView wvob=(WebView)myObject;
    wvob.setName("ola");    
}
```

setName method is with WebView class.So Object class reference cant find it.

Comment: Cheers, corrected it and understand it a little bit

Comment: @BashirskCFC IMHO casting is not a good option here, design is wrong (declaring `myObject` or any other attribute as `Object` is not a good practice). This solution is ignoring wrong design and making an ugly workaround.

Comment: @JordiCastilla I havent casted it, i have just used the object and called the method and added an argument to it `myObject.setName("sk");`